# C++ how to rename a data member

Tags: c++

I receive a class A from an external supplier. On the 1st version of A, A has a data member a1. In the next delivery (version 2), a1 has been renamed a2, which has the exact same role as a1. (The supplier has good reasons for doing that.)
How can I deal with that w/o changing my code?
We are using C++17.

Comment: Q: How can I deal with that w/o changing my code?  A: You can't.  You can 1) modify your code to use the new class with the new member, or 2) create a new [facade](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/facade_pattern.htm) class that abstracts the difference(s)

Comment: How is the class delivered to you (header file only, header + binary, header + source)?  Since you don't want to change your code, is adding a compiler argument something you can do?  Is the identifier `a1` used for anything else in your code other than referring to that data member?

Comment: More details please.  How are you incorporating the code from the external supplier?  As a source drop?  As a pre-compiled lib with a header file?  Why are you unable to just run search and replace on your own code?

Comment: That you directly access inner data members with its name is curious! One core idiom of object oriented programming is encapsulation. Direct access member vars is definitly the opposite. But yes, you can write a wrapper around where in the wrapper class a1 is a wrapper itself with all operators overloaded and forwarding to underlying variable,,, but hey? It is much easier to change all access points by refactoring functionality of your IDE. And while doing that, think about the pure design.

Comment: Be careful. With this problem, any "easy" solution will set you up for bigger trouble in the future. Been there. Done that. Hated it soon afterwards.

Comment: @Klaus pure OOP is history. In C++ nowadays we use data-oriented design.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good example of why exposing members on a class directly can lead to maintenance issues later and having getters is a good idea. I would advise you and the supplier to provide a (const) getter method instead of exposing a member and add this to your technical debt.

For now you might be able to do something like this hack for the moment

```
#include <iostream>/

class A_new_version
{
public:
    int a2{ 42 };
};

class A :
    public A_new_version
{
public:
    // create an "alias" reference to a2
    int& a1 = a2;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.a1 = 12; // now you can access a2 with name a1

    // and also start with using the new name
    std::cout << a.a2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A public member should be public rather than putting boilerplate getter methods everywhere. A person can just as easily change the name of a getter from `getA1` to `getA2`. Before any of this happened, the person providing the class should have taken all parts of the public API, whether data members or methods, to be unchanged in an effort not to break client code. The only possible advantage to using a getter method is you can technically change its implementation details later, but realistically, no one changes a member to a calculated value or different type.

Comment: After developing in C++ for 30 years (and maintaining code that has lasted almost as long) I respectfully disagree. Public members break encapsulation. Setters/getters allow for the class internals to be refactored at a later time without breaking the interface. Also setters allow for input checks, addition of logging and possibly even the sending of notifications at a later stage. The boiler plate code as you call it is minimal and IMO well worth the effort now. And yes I do agree the supplier should not just have changed the existing API.

Comment: Your hack would behave differently after a assignment...

Comment: Yeah it is a hack. The problem should be fixed at third party first and then propagated in the client code.

Answer (score 0):

If the only use of `a1` in your code is to refer to that specific data member, you can simply using `#define` to fix all occurrences of `a1` in your code.  For safety, it would be best to put the `#define` in a position after you have included all the header files that are external to your project (like other libraries or system header files).

For example:

```c
#include <iostream>      // External includes
#include <libsomething>  // Library that defines a2
// No more includes of foreign code below here

#define a1 a2

// ... your code, which uses a1 ...
```

However, it's probably better for the long-term health of your code if you can just change `a1` to `a2` in the source code instead of using the preprocessor.